# How to convert a postgresql JSONB column into array column

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in the table which stores polygon points in jsonb,

```
position
---------------
[{"x": 455, "y": -3165},{"x": 455,"y": 50},  {"x": 5708,"y": 50}]
```

I want to turn the jsonb into array, like this:

```
position_array
-----------------
((455, -3165),(455, 50), (5708, 50))
```

I can't figout a simple way to do this. Pls help

Comment: What exactly is the type of that second value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce0953959a5550f92c987d33b8cd35d5)

```
SELECT 
    array_agg(                            -- 4
        ARRAY[                            -- 3
            (elems -> 'x')::int,
            (elems -> 'y')::int           -- 2
        ]
    )
FROM
    t,
    jsonb_array_elements(data) as elems   -- 1
```

1. Extract all array elements into one row per element
2. Fetch `x`/`y` values
3. Aggregate `x`/`y` into an array
4. Aggregate these arrays into one global array

Comment: What is the advantage to doing jsonb_array_elements  as opposed to using jsonb_to_recordset with a composite type?

Comment: Although I see this is a right answer but I dont quite get the 'from t, jsonb_array_elements(data)' part, this looks a table join?

Comment: @georgehu Because `jsonb_array_elements` is a set-returning function, the , character is the shortcut for a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` (if it were a table join, it would be a simple `CROSS JOIN`): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/understanding-joined-set-returning-functions-in-the-from-list

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb)` function, from [the official PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html)

To quote the docs:

> Expands the top-level JSON array of objects to a set of rows having the composite type defined by an AS clause

In this case, we need to apply `jsonb_to_recordset` to the actual jsonb itself. This will allow postgres to think about your jsonb array as a set of rows that follow a composite type definition, which is defined by `AS (x int, y int)` in your case. This tells postgres that, once it has finished transforming the `jsonb` into a recordset, it should pluck out the `x` and `y` keys in your `jsonb` and treat them as integers.

[You can read more about composite types here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rowtypes.html)

That looks like this (I simply copied and pasted your raw jsonb in here):

```
jsonb_to_recordset('[{"x": 455, "y": -3165},{"x": 455,"y": 50},  {"x": 5708,"y": 50}]') AS position(x int, y int);
```

If you run:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"x": 455, "y": -3165},{"x": 455,"y": 50},  {"x": 5708,"y": 50}]') AS (x int, y int);
```

You'll see that it gives you 3 rows with columns `x` and `y` containing the expected values from each object in your `jsonb`.

Next, you're going to want to use `array_agg` to turn this into your final desired array. However, you'll need to specify that what you want to aggregate is actually `array[x, y]` -- this will effectively aggregate an array of arrays with shape `{x, y}`, where `x` and `y` are both ints coming from your composite type `AS (x int, y int)`.

Putting it all together, this should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT array_agg(array[x, y]) as position_array FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"x": 455, "y": -3165},{"x": 455,"y": 50},  {"x": 5708,"y": 50}]') AS (x int, y int);
```

Outputting:

`{{455,-3165},{455,50},{5708,50}}`

Just a quick note: in Postgres, arrays are defined with `{` instead of `(` :)